# "A man should look at the woman he wants to marry to get induced to marry her": How should a blind man do about it?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, non-mahram

We know that if a man intends to marry a girl he is allowed to see her -however scholars may differ in their interpretation on what he may see of her- based on the hadith:

> Narrated Jabir ibn Abdullah:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) said: When one of you asked a woman in marriage, if he is able to look at what will induce him to marry her, he should do so. He (Jabir) said: I asked a girl in marriage, I used to look at her secretly, until I looked at what induced me to marry her. I, therefore, married her. ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/37))

So what is the case for a blind man:

- As he is not able to see and blind people usually use their hands to get a picture of things, what is he allowed to do or what should he do to get induced to marry her? Especially as touching does not sound like a shari'a conform option?

Answer (score 2):

Its permitted for the man to send someone else to see her on his behalf and then describe her to him, a blind man can take this option.  This intermediary is either a woman relative of him or a mahram relative of woman.

Comment: With some references and an explanation why touching in this case is no option this answer would be more helpful!